# Matrices in latex

Tags: matrices, arrays

Trying to create a matrix using the below markup:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccccccc}
I & like & nlp & mlpr & enjoy & reading & books \\
\begin{block}{[ccccccc]c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & I \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & like \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & nlp \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & mlpr \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & enjoy \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & reading \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & books \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\caption{A caption to the entire figure}
\end{figure}
```

The output that I get is as below:

[image]

As you can see, that the columns of the matrix are unevenly spaced. It would be great if I can get evenly spaced columns.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could put each of the labels into a fixed width box.  `\makebox[1cm][c]{\textit{reading}}`

Comment: Why do you use `\[ ... \]` inside of `figure`?

Comment: It's possible to use a `\BAnewcolumntype` which does automatically has a width of `1cm` etc.

Comment: Could you show up please and give some feedback on the solutions here?

Answer (score 12):

Warning: I am no `blkarray` expert ;-)

However, it's possible to define a new column type (say B) for `blockarray` which uses the same width for all columns with this specifier.

Since there 7 columns with this feature, one could shorten the `ccccccc` and replace with `*{7}B` as in usual tabular environments.

I've to find out, whether `\BAnewcolumntype` supports on column type with an argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\BAnewcolumntype{B}{>{\centering}p{1cm}}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
$
\begin{blockarray}{cccccccc}
\text{I} & \text{like} & \text{nlp} & \text{mlpr} & \text{enjoy} & \text{reading} & \text{books} \\
\begin{block}{[*{7}B]c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{I} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{like} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{nlp} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{mlpr} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{enjoy} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{reading} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{books} \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
$

\caption{A caption to the entire figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MikeRenfro: It's not clear that the OP doesn't want to have the text in math mode, so this edit is a little bit too fast, in my point of view

Comment: Fair enough. Feel free to revert back to the original.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Nope, I keep it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm pretty sure the OP has the mental capacity to remove the `\text` - additionally, if the OP didn't want the text and indeed the headings as math, the OP should be shot.

Comment: @AlecTeal: The point is that answers shouldn't be edited unless there is a severe error. Give edit or addition suggestions in a comment rather

Comment: "answers shouldn't be edited unless there is a severe error" [citation needed]

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Nope, this is my rule, for my answers, as well as I don't edit other answers.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, but you don't get to make rules unilaterally. Answers that you contribute are licensed under Creative Commons and people are free to edit them. See the [help centre](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/editing) for more information.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yes, that's right, but I still have to right to rollback. It's a matter of respect asking for editing or to edit working answers only on a pure assumption that `\text{...}` might look better or not.

Answer (score 2):

The `tabstackengine` package has a fixed width option for arrays, which I employ here.  Because of that, I merely needed to make a single entry of the "1" array of the same width as the word "reading" and the rest was resolved. I accomplished that with `\tmpbox`.

The package also allows either text or math to be stacked, which I used here to stack the text as text and the numbers as math.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\fixTABwidth{T}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\[
\stackText
\setbox0=\hbox{reading}
\savestack{\tmpbox}{\makebox[\wd0]{$1$}}
\savestack{\toprow}{\tabbedCenterstack{I & like & nlp & mlpr & enjoy & reading & books}}
\ensurestackMath{
\stackon{\bracketMatrixstack{
\tmpbox & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \cr
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \cr
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \cr
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \cr
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \cr
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \cr
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
}}{\toprow}}
\Centerstack{ I \cr  like \cr nlp \cr mlpr \cr enjoy \cr reading \cr books}
\]
\caption{A caption to the entire figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The inter-column gap is set to 1ex with `\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}`.  If one wished the inter-row baselineskip to be larger, the line `\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}` could be added to the preamble to achieve the following result:

[image]

Finally, one could left-align the right-hand  column of words by adding a `[l]` optional argument to the `\Centerstack`.

Answer (score 1):

A variant with one less column, and 7 blocks, with `\Right{.}{text}` at the end of the preamble of each block. I also use the `eqparbox` package to ensure equal width columns, without having to find by trials and errors what will be the right size:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\BAnewcolumntype{B}{>{\centering}p{1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering\makeatletter\setlength\tabcolsep{-10pt}\BA@colsep =1pt\makeatother
  $
  \begin{blockarray}{*{7}{c}}
    \eqmakebox[C]{I} & \eqmakebox[C]{like} & \eqmakebox[C]{nlp} & \eqmakebox[C]{mlpr} & \eqmakebox[C]{enjoy} & \eqmakebox[C]{reading} & \eqmakebox[C]{books} \\
    \begin{block}{*{7}{c}\Right{.}{I}}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{*{7}{c}\Right{.}{like}}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{*{7}{c}\Right{.}{nlp}}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{*{7}{c}\Right{.}{mlpr}}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{*{7}{c}\Right{.}{enjoy}}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{*{7}{c}\Right{.}{reading}}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{*{7}{c}\Right{.}{books}}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
  $

  \caption{A caption to the entire figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]